# Join string and variable to get another variable in PHP

Tags: php, string, variables

Sorry if this has already been asked, but it's hard to search for it... I tried googlin this topic without success.

What I want to do is this:

```
$layoutColor = 2;
$colors1 = array ("F57171", "FACCCC");
$colors2 = array ("FF9900", "FFC66F");

$chosenTheme = "colors".$layoutColor;
echo $chosenTheme [0];
```

I want to join the $layoutColor variable with the word "colors" in order to get the variable $colors2.

How do I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: You want to treat a string as a name of another variable?

Comment: I want to join them both, to get another variable... I used to do this all the time in ActionScript, but I don't how to write it in PHP.

I will have a lot of $colors arrays, like $color35, $color36...
I wan't to be able to just change the number in the variable $layoutColor, and with that, the variable $chosenTheme will automatically be equal to the colors I want.

Comment: It's called variable variables, and you do **NOT** want to go there. They lead to utterly unmaintainable code. Use a multidimensional array instead: `$colors[1][1] -> FACCCC`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're best off approaching this by just combining all your options into a single multi-dimensional array:

```
$layoutColor = 2;
$colors = array();
$colors[1] = array ("F57171", "FACCCC");
$colors[2] = array ("FF9900", "FFC66F");

$chosenTheme = $colors[$layoutColor];
echo $chosenTheme [0];
```

Comment: I haven't thought about this, this seems to be the best way to do it indeed. Much better.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<?php
$layoutColor = 2;
$colors1 = array ("F57171", "FACCCC");
$colors2 = array ("FF9900", "FFC66F");

$chosenTheme = "colors".$layoutColor;
echo ${$chosenTheme}[0];
```

Prints:

> FF9900

Comment: While I maintain that a multidimensional array is the best approach here, this answer is a more direct answer to the question. +1

Comment: Agreed. This works perfectly, but the multidimensional array seems to be the better choice for me. I just didn't thought about it... Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can simplify this using multi dimensional arrays:

```
$colors = array(
    array ("F57171", "FACCCC"),
    array ("FF9900", "FFC66F")
);
```

So...

```
echo $colors[0];
```

Or you can user variable variables:

```
$chosenTheme = ${"colors".$layoutColor};
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try this

```
$layoutColor = 2;
$$colors2 = "colors".$layoutColor;
```

So you'll get `$colors2` variable

```
print_r($colors2); // Array ( [0] => FF9900 [1] => FFC66F )
```

Notice the double `$`, that will keep the variable name in the variable.

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
$layoutColor = 2;

$string = "color";

echo $$string.$layoutColor;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use dynamic variables
    `$$chosenTheme = "colors".$layoutColor;`

then access the array by using this variable
    `$chosenTheme`

Answer (score 0):

This might not be an answer to your question but, depending on your specific context, try something like this:

```
$layoutColor = 2;
$colors = array (
               Array("F57171", "FACCCC"),
               Array ("FF9900", "FFC66F")
           );

echo $colors[$layoutColor][0];
```

A multi dimensional array is a lot easier to read